# Delete List Item with Ajax

Tags: list, ajax

I've been trying a few options out, but I'm finding good SharePoint AJAX guides to either not exist or be hard to find.

Very simple, I am rendering list items with a repeater, and I want to be able to delete them via AJAX. I can render the List Item ID in the element, so I would just need to be able to delete a list item with it's List ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you talking about SP 2010?

Then you can use either the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)  or you can use the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011.aspx).